# In an array of hash how to delete an element with particular value for a key in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In an array of hash how to delete an element with particular value for a key?

For example:

```
array = [ {"lang"=> 'Ruby', "is_using"=> "Yes"}, { "lang"=> "Go", "is_using" => "No"}, {"lang"=> "Rust", "is_using"=> "No"} ]
```

I need to write a minimal and efficient ruby script which deletes all the elements from the array which has "No" as a value for the key "is_using".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if):

```
array = [ {"lang"=> 'Ruby', "is_using"=> "Yes"}, { "lang"=> "Go", "is_using" => "No"}, {"lang"=> "Rust", "is_using"=> "No"} ]
array.delete_if { |hash| hash['is_using'] == 'No' }
#=> [{ "lang" => "Ruby", "is_using" => "Yes" }]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mutate the original array, then you could use `reject`:

```
array = [{ "lang"=> 'Ruby', "is_using"=> "Yes" },
         { "lang"=> "Go", "is_using" => "No" },
         { "lang"=> "Rust", "is_using"=> "No" }]

array.reject { |h| h["is_using"].eql?('Yes') }
# [{"lang"=>"Go", "is_using"=>"No"}, {"lang"=>"Rust", "is_using"=>"No"}]
```

Comment: I did want to mutate the original array, anyways thanks :)

Comment: Ah okay. That's fine.

Comment: You should probably be using "No" instead of "Yes" @Rajagopalan (otherwise use `select`).

Comment: Thanks for editiing nicely. And coming to your point. What's wrong in that? I am rejecting the hash which has 'is_using' yes, what's the problem here?